# Website structure / Newbie

Tags: php

I created a website using php, passing values from page to page either with POST or GET.

Though there is some cons, I dont know how to track specifically what data has been viewed in GoogleAnalytics as it just shows the name of the page (xxxx.php)

On the other side, I see websites structured differently with a bunch of subdirectories created : www.xxx.com/xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx

This looks like pretty manual for me , compared to the .php?xxxx=xxxx way of structuring.

Do you know how this subdirectory style structuring can be automatically obtained?

Answer (score 2):

This is done with Apache rewrite rules.

To make it so that whenever a user goes to `/posts/visiting_new_york`, it actually goes to to `/viewpost.php?id=visiting_new_york`, you create a file in your site called `.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule '^posts/([^/]+)$' viewpost.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an MVC framework like rails, or simply configure your webserver's virtual directory structure to be identical to the local servers file system and adhere to that scheme when saving your php files.

Comment: Many Thanks, your answer as well as others do help understand. I had an architecture in mind that was too much old fashioned. I will read about frameworks, MVC, url rewriting... lots of work ahead : ) thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with "mod_rewrite" in apache.

It involves creating a .htaccess file with URL re-writing rules inside.

So you can transform /index.php?page=contact&lang=en into /en/contact/

Here's a good rewrite cheat sheet: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/

Wadih

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about url rewriting

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

If you just want to track your dynamic pages , there is another solution in Google analytic

http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55504